# concatenate XML values using dataweave mule

Tags: mule, dataweave

We have a scenario where we need to concatenate all XML node values to String.

**input XML**

```
<root>
  <line>1</line>
  <line>2</line>
  <line>3</line>
  <line>4</line>
</root>
```

**Output to String**

1234

Please let me know how can i achieve in form of String.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring [DataWeave Reference Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation) at **Reduce** section:

Transform

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
concat: ["a", "b", "c", "d"] reduce ($$ ++ $)
```

Output

```
{
  "concat": "abcd"
}
```

Therefore, you can try something like this: `concat: payload.root.*line reduce ($$ ++ $)`

Comment: Thanks for reply Sulthony.  <br/> I am getting following warning **There is no variable named '$'**.  <br>

Comment: Hm... apparently it's a bug in Dataweave. I tried `concat: ["1", "2", "3", "4"] reduce $$ + $` the result is `{ "concat": 10 }`, it means working properly.
But when add extra `+` for string concatenation as mentioned in documentation `concat: ["1", "2", "3", "4"] reduce $$ ++ $`, I also get the same warning.

Comment: Parenthesis around the lambda seem to do the trick: payload.root.*line reduce ($$ ++ $).

Comment: Wow, that works. Thanks Ryan... (I edit my answer then)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    result: payload.root.*line reduce ((item ,acc="") -> acc ++ item)
}
```