# concatenate XML values with different tag names using dataweave mule

Tags: mule, dataweave

We have a scenario where we need to concatenate all XML node values to String.

input XML

```
<root>
<Address>
  <line1>1</line1>
  <line2>2</line2>
  <line3>3</line3>
  <line4>4</line4>
</Address>
<PostCode>
  <line5>5<line5>
</PostCode>
</root>
```

Output to String

1 2 3 4 5

Please let me know how can i achieve in form of String.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is already answered here [concatenate XML values using dataweave mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614590/concatenate-xml-values-using-dataweave-mule)

Referring [DataWeave Reference Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation) at **Reduce** section:

Transform

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
concat: ["a", "b", "c", "d"] reduce ($$ ++ $)
```

Output

```
{
 "concat": "abcd"
}
```

Therefore, you can try something like this: `concat: payload.root.*line reduce ($$ ++ $)`

Comment: The tags are of different names,  line1, line2 and not the same 'line' as in the earlier post pointed to

Comment: ok, I was able to achieve using [payload.root.line1,payload.root.line2,payload.root.line3] reduce ($$ ++ $). Thanks